# Laravel unique method, log for every collection match found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm filtering out non-unique arrays from my collection based only on a combination of if the "first_name" and "last_name" matches any others, but I want to drop a console.log for every match found. I've thought about using a foreach in a foreach to check element against one another, but that method seems far from elegant.

Is it possible to do this while using the Laravel Unique() method without using nested forEach's?

Example of what I'm currently doing:

```php
$collection->unique(function ($item) {
    return $item['first_name'].$item['last_name'];
})->each(function ($item, $key) use ($id) {
    // Do stuff..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First store duplicates:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]);
$duplicates = $collection->duplicates();
```

Then make your collection unique and store:

```
$collection = $collection->unique();
```

Output:

[image: Output of collections in array]

References:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-duplicates

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-unique